# GCP Cloud Armor deny main domain https://mma.mydomain.com/

Tags: google-cloud-platform, re2, google-cloud-armor

Is there a way to deny https://mma.mydomain.com/ main domain and allow the below Web sevices in GCP Cloud armor.

```
1. https://mma.mydomain.com/v1/teststudio/developer - POST
2. https://mma.mydomain.com/v1/teststudio/developer - GET
3. https://mma.mydomain.com/v1/teststudio/developer - PATCH
4. https://mma.mydomain.com/v1/teststudio/developer/app - POST
5. https://mma.mydomain.com/v1/teststudio/developer/app - GET
```

I have set the below rules in Google Cloud Armor Network Security services

```
 deny       request.path.matches('https://mma.mydomain.com/')   Deny access from Internet to https://mma.mydomain.com       28      

 Allow      request.path.matches('/v1/devstudio/developer')     Allow access from Internet to /v1/teststudio/developer      31      

 Allow      request.path.matches('/v1/devstudio/developer')     Allow access from Internet to /v1/teststudio/developer/app  32
```

I am referring to https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rules-language-reference. Please guide with examples.

Thanks in Advance.

Best Regards,

Kaushal

Comment: You should write the rules and then when you have a problem post a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What do you mean you set the below? Can you share with us the rules that you have created and then once created is there any error message that you are getting or any result that you dont expect?

Comment: @YvanG. I have shared the GCP Cloud Armor rules in the post.

Comment: Upon sharing the rules, is there any error message that you are getting? What behavior do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your numbers to the right are the rule priorities, Cloud Armor will match the first rule and stop. In your case, it will match the hostname value and deny the request and never consider the other rules. Consider reversing the flow and have the more specific allow rules first and then fire the "default" hostname rule.

consider a rule like this:
request.headers['host'].matches('mma.mydomain.com') && request.path.lower().urlDecode().contains('/v1/devstudio/developer') && request.method == "GET"

And if you want to block other requests, have your request.path.matches('https://mma.mydomain.com/')  rule fire after